# How do I create fold lines on my dieline?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, packaging

I'm working on a dieline for a box and I was wondering how I could make the fold lines.

Do I just make the stroke dashed?

I'm using rectangles to create my dieline. How do I select just one side of the rectangle to make my fold line? Every time I select one side the whole rectangle gets selected.

Answer (score 1):

In illustrator you cannot have different styles (strokes or dashes) on the boxes your referring to without a hack job. In your case, it might be easiest to `Press C` and then click the two points that create the line you want to dash. This will remove the line via scissor tool from the box and create it's own object. It might disappear behind your object so you may need to bring it forward. Then you alter its appearance.

When two boxes are intersecting, you can just delete the other line via the same method so you have just one dashed line through the composition.